# Redux store is updating but connected function that is called by setInterval still sees the old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, setinterval, react-redux

**I am trying to make my app have the following behavior:**
 - When the user clicks "Start Timers" a timer runs
 - A message is printed to the console when the timer ends
 - The number of seconds that have elapsed since the timer started is displayed

**My project is at:**
https://github.com/harimau777/reduxTimerExample

**My strategy for implementing this is:**
When the user clicks "Start Timers", handleStartTimers is called.  handleStartTimers starts an interval with a one second duration that calls handleTick when it expires.  It then dispatches a startTimers action.

The general logic of handleTick is:

```
if this is the last tick in the timer:
  Print that the timer has finished
  Reset the timer
else:
  Dispatch an incrementTickCount action
```

**The problem that I am having is:**

- When I click startTimers the number of seconds since the start of the
  timer displayed on the page increments each second.  This indicates
  that the store is correctly being updated and that handleTick is
  successfully dispatching the incrementTickCount action.
- However, handleTick never gets the updated state so it always sees
  the tickCount as 0 and therefore never prints that the timer has finished.

**Things that I have tried without success:**

- I have tried either including or not including handleTick in the
  component's mapDispatchToProps.
- I have tried wrapping handleTick in a function when I pass it to
  setInterval.
- I have tried passing the props to handleTick and not passing them in
  order to use closure scope.
- I have tried binding handleTick's "this"; however, I get that "this"
  is undefined.
- I have tried defining handleTick as a nested function of startTimers
  to see if this would somehow allow it to have the correct scope.
- I have tried various combinations of the previous approaches.

I am guessing that either I am handling scope wrong or that there is some aspect of how Redux passes state to components or rerenders that I am not understanding.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create a small project where issue is addressed, not the full application, so we can go through it as fast as possible

Comment: Sorry about that.  I made a simplified version of the project that just displays the problem I am having and edited my question.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right,

in your controller when you click on startTimers, the tickCounter is 0. In the scope of your interval it gets never updated. So `handleTick` will always read the value 0.

Yes the incrementAction performs the work and the tickCounter in your store gets updated, but you don't have state object in your actionCreator function (handleStartTimers), this is why the following expression is always false:

`if (tickCount === duration * 60){`

An easy way of fixing it, would be to perform the incrementation inside the interval, instead of the action, it would also make sense because you are dealing with time, so you cannot rely on the setInterval function, as it never will be 100% 1000ms, but always after 1000ms. So you could set something like:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
  var seconds = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000);
  setPassedSeconds(seconds, intervalId);
}, 1000);
```

This way you can also change the interval time, without changing the code in your actions / reducer..

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble passing state to children unless they are first order values in mapStateToProps. Try this;

```js
const TimerList = ({timers, increment, decrement, addTimer, removeTimer}) => (
  <div className="timerList">
    {console.log('Timers are:', timers)}
    {
      timers.map((timer, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <div className="timer">
            <h1>Timer {index}</h1>
            <span>Duration: {timer} minutes</span>
            <span className='button' onClick={() => increment(index)}>Increment</span>
            <span className='button' onClick={() => decrement(index)}>Decrement</span>
          </div>
          <span className="button" onClick={() => removeTimer(index)}>Remove Timer</span>
        </div>
      ))
    }

    <span className="button" onClick={addTimer}>Add Timer</span>
  </div>
);
```